# Createded Element Showing as undefined object

Tags: javascript, methods, createelement

I am trying to create a delete button to put in the last cell of my table. But when I try it out, it shows the object definition ([object HTMLButtonElement]) rather than the HTML element it's supposed to generate. Does it have to be appended to the table row somehow? Since I am just creating normal HTML tags in the loop, how do I do that?

When I try the method in the console, it produces the element as I would expect.

Also, it's adding "undefined" just after the opening 'table' tag. Seems a little strange.

```js
var view = {
  //It should be able to display staff
  displayStaff: function() {
    var staffTable = document.getElementById("staffInfo");

    staffTable.innerHTML = "";
    staffTable.innerHTML = "<table><tbody><tr><th>Staff Name</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Staff Number</th><th>Department</th><th>Seniority</th><th>Email Address</th><th>Employment Status</th><th>Action</th></tr>"
    + this.listStaffProps() + "</tbody></table>";
  
  },
  listStaffProps: function() {
    var staffList;
    for (var props in rotaOb.staff) {
      staffList += "<tr><td>" + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_fName + " " + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_sName
      + "</td><td>" + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_pNumber
      + "</td><td>" + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_staffN
      + "</td><td>" + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_dept
      + "</td><td>" + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_seniority
      + "</td><td>" + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_sEmail
      + "</td><td>" + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_fullTime
      + "</td><td>" + this.deleteStaffButton()
      + "</td></tr>";
    };
    return staffList;
  },
  deleteStaffButton: function() {
    var deleteStaffButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    deleteStaffButton.textContent = "Delete";
    deleteStaffButton.className = "deleteStaffButton";
    return deleteStaffButton;
  }
};
```

Comment: Initialize `staffList`, `var staffList = "";`! Or otherwise you'll get a `"undefined"` prepended to your HTML stored in `staffList`.

Comment: Hi, just tried that, still not working. :(

Comment: You're mixing text creation and object creation- you should pick your poison, or not try to append an object to a string. `document.createElement()` returns an object, you're trying to add it to the back of your string, you can use `{{element}}.appendChild()`

Comment: As @wizebin said, change the last function so that it return a HTML string instead of a node!

Comment: this is somewhat difficult to troubleshoot without all the  codes needed what is what is rotaOb? ReferenceError: rotaOb is not defined. where is the div staffInfo? this is another error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either change your `deleteStaffButton` function or you can change the way you add the button to your table.

Easiest change would be to modify the function (but then you don't have the flexibility of adding a function directly) so it returns an HTML string.

```
deleteStaffButton: function() {
  return '<button class="deleteStaffButton">Delete</button>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a string since your parsing HTML.

> ```
> var deleteStaffButton = "<button class='deleteStaffButton'>Delete</button>"
> ```
>
> and add the var in:
>
> ```
>  + "</td><td>" + deleteStaffButton
> ```

or simply:

> ```
>  + "</td><td><button class='deleteStaffButton'>Delete</button></td></tr>"
> ```

since it's not going to change.

**Snippet**

```js
var view = {
  //It should be able to display staff
  displayStaff: function() {
    var staffTable = document.getElementById("staffInfo");

    staffTable.innerHTML = "";
    staffTable.innerHTML = "<table><tbody><tr><th>Staff Name</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Staff Number</th><th>Department</th><th>Seniority</th><th>Email Address</th><th>Employment Status</th><th>Action</th></tr>"
    + this.listStaffProps() + "</tbody></table>";
  
  },
  listStaffProps: function() {
    var staffList;
    for (var props in rotaOb.staff) {
      staffList += "<tr><td>" + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_fName + " " + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_sName
      + "</td><td>" + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_pNumber
      + "</td><td>" + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_staffN
      + "</td><td>" + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_dept
      + "</td><td>" + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_seniority
      + "</td><td>" + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_sEmail
      + "</td><td>" + rotaOb.staff[props].staff_fullTime
      + "</td><td>" + deleteStaffButton
      + "</td></tr>";
    };
    return staffList;
  },
  var deleteStaffButton = "<button class='deleteStaffButton'>Delete</button>"

  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var deleteStaffButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var text = deleteStaffButton.textContent = "Delete";
deleteStaffButton.appendChild(text);
```